# How to implement custom gallery in Android with half images being displayed on right and left end and a full image in the middle?

Tags: android, gallery, android-custom-view

[image]

Please help me in implementing the gallery like as in image attached. I wish the images to be clickable and while left-right swipe, the new images in the left and right make similar configuration. On right swipe Full image goes and settles to the place of half right image, left half image settles to the full middle image and a new image from the left comes and settles at the left half image. Similar configuration is required on left swipe.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: I think you can use viewpager with fragments

Comment: I have list of images and I want to show only the half part of the images on the right and left. The image in the middle is only displayed fully.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this it you need to follow below steps
1. Create gallery 
2. Create image adapter
3. Set width of gallery and view of adapter (image view) according to your need.

if you want some simple view then please follow below link:

https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow
https://github.com/JakeWharton/salvage
https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager

I hope, it will help for you.